# How do I use zlib in a react app? or what is zlib_binding and why is it missing?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have created a brand new react app using VS2022 and create-react-app.
I have installed `zlib` using `npm install zlib`.

getting the following error when running `npm run start`:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/zlib/lib/zlib.js 1:0-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zlib_bindings' in 'c:\projects\mall\mall\node_modules\zlib\lib'
```

To troubleshoot, I created a `test.js` file with just `require('zlib')` in it and it works.

file `./node_modules/zlib/lib/zlib.js` has `import './zlib_bindings'` as a single line in it. But there is no `./zlib_bindings.js`.

Questions:

1. How do I fix this?
2. How does that work when I run `node test.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `test.js` file works because you run it with node.

> The zlib module provides compression functionality implemented using
> Gzip and Deflate/Inflate. It is the part of nodejs core module written
> in c++

This module can't be used outside of node.js

You can however try to use `react-zlib-js` and it should work!

Comment: What threw me off is that it was working in codesandbox, I didn't realize codesandbox browserfies the code.